# Add Zendesk Chat widget for agent in our web portal

Tags: chat, zendesk

I want to integrate Zendesk Chat widget for Agent  login through our web portal not through zendesk support portal.

Zendesk is providing Chat widget for end users only which as below

```
<script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=abcdeasdfasdfasdfas"> </script>
```

For Agent I have to login through zendesk portal only to chat with end users or customers

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the Conversations API by Zendesk Chat yet? https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/chat/conversations-api

Comment: feedback I recieved from zendesk support on this: I'm afraid not. Chat conversation API lets your application act as a Zendesk Chat agent and interact with customers who use the Zendesk Web Widget or the Zendesk Chat Widget like a chatbot. The behavior you'd like to change is part of the browser, tapping on the back button of the mobile browser is initiate go-back function for the website, there's no way to get this applied for the chat widget.

Comment: With this API, you can make your own widget.  If you want to just take the Zendesk agent widget, then I don't think it's possible.  But to implement a chat widget in your own portal, you should be able to use the Conversations API to make a custom Widget.  This API will provide a data interface with Zendesk Chat, and you would need to build the UI.